# TCL :: how to puts backslash "\" as regular character

Tags: tcl

I cannot print backslash as regular character.

> puts "\"

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puts "\\"
should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping it:

```
puts \\
```

Or possibly:

```
puts [format %c 92]
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe will be helpful , can use echo :

echo {\ }

thanks

Comment: echo is not a Tcl command. And if it were, what you propose is not correct, as it would output "\ " (backslash followed by space), and not a single backslash as desired